# Stereo audio input on any Android device?

Tags: audio

Is there **any** Android device with a stereo audio input available?

I understand there is the analog microphone input commonly available on the headphone jack, but I am hoping there is a device out there that might have a stereo audio input hidden away on a dual-use USB port or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news!  Android 5.0 has support for audio capture via USB class-compliant devices.

You'll probably have to use your device at 48 kHz, and mixer control isn't supported, but at least it's something.

My Zoom H4n works out of the box with a Galaxy S6.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Olimex OLinuXino A10S - https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A10S/