# Can a device running Android OS record a stereo audio source?

Tags: audio-recording, 8.0-oreo

[This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26585/stereo-audio-input-on-any-android-device) question is very old. Time to ask again, because hardware and software changes. The question is simple.

What have I tried?

1. Searched here. Dead links.
2. Read up on OTG.
3. Got a Roland Go Mixer. Monitor jack outputs stereo, specialized app records mono, other apps still record the phone mic.
4. I find out that this is a long standing issue, and that neither the OTG USB sound card nor the specialized app is to blame.

So the question is simple, and I suspect the answer is very simply, no. Not on any device running Android OS, with any audio hardware, with any audio driver, with any specially written app therefor.

So, as per the title: Is there an exception?